# Ubuntu 14.04 Brightness level problem

Tags: ubuntu, brightness

I know we had a lots of questions about that problem but none worked for me. I have a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04 but cannot change the brightness level just when I use Linux. The only way I've found to change it is using Nvidia Xserver application but I had read that this is not the properly way to do that.
When I try to decrease the brightness level the bar on the top of the screen appears and tells me that it's decreasing but nothing happens.
Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. Used this link and it works perfectly now. Although updating to the latest version of Ubuntu fixes it as well. 
http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

Comment: Don't just post a link. Summarise what the link tells you to do.  Links die and links change.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
Did you use this solution with Ubuntu 14.04 too ?